# Why is if statement returning False?

Tags: python

```
ALL_CONSONANTS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
HIDDEN = '^'`

def is_bonus_letter(lowercase_letter: str, phrase_puzzle: str,
                    current_view: str) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if lowercase_letter is a bonus letter related
    to phrase_puzzle and current_view.

    >>> is_bonus_letter('k', 'talk', 't^l^')
    True
    >>> is_bonus_letter('l', 'love', 'l^v^')
    False
    """
    if ((lowercase_letter in ALL_CONSONANTS) and
        (lowercase_letter in phrase_puzzle) and
        (lowercase_letter in HIDDEN)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_bonus_letter('k', 'talk', 't^l^'))  # -> False
```

The output of `is_bonus_letter('k', 'talk', 't^l^')` should be `True`, but I keep getting `False`.
Why?

Comment: Why is the code in the question not indented correctly?

Comment: I don't quite understand the function. Why is `current_view` not used anywhere?

Comment: You're checking to see if "k" is in HIDDEN and the answer is False.  This is part of an "and" statement, so the function returns False.  Did you mean `k not in HIDDEN`?

Comment: Also "if <cond> return True else return False" is redundant. Just say "return <cond>"

Comment: Hi, It is just one part of many questions. I am just trying to get this if statement work. I am sorry for the non-indented code.

Comment: @ewon that's fine, but per stackoverflow guidlines you should try to reproduce a minimal example of your problem, rather than posting the whole code block. You will attract better answers if you try and strip down the question to only the information that is needed to solve the problem. Often, in doing this, you will also realise the answer before you even finish typing the question, I've found at least. so yea take out that current_view it isn't relevant.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `lowercase_letter in HIDDEN` which is false since `HIDDEN = '^'` and `lowercase_letter` is `t` which does not exist in `^`

Perhaps you meant to check `lowercase_letter in current_view`, as it would seem `current_view` is unused?

In general when you have two options, returning true or false, depending on many conditions, you can quickly find the answer by commenting out all of the conditions, then adding one back at a time until you pin point which one is causing it

Answer (score 0):

Your program returns False because 'k' is not in 't^l^'. if you want it to return True, lowercase_letter would have to be 't' or 'l', OR you would have to edit your if statement.  Right now, your program returns false because `(lowercase_letter in HIDDEN)` is false.

Comment: You're on the right track but HIDDEN is not 't^|^' it's just '^'

Comment: ie "t" or "|" would also not work, so this is incorrect